# Hangfire, Autofac and WebApi

Tags: asp.net-web-api, autofac, hangfire

I recently learned about Hangfire but had no luck with it so far. My project uses autofac so I've added HangFire.1.4.3 & HangFire.Autofac.1.1.0 nuget packages to my project. Followed by documentation I've created Startup class and registered Hangfire there

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
      GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
                    .UseSqlServerStorage("NavigatorConnectionString");

       app.UseHangfireDashboard();
       app.UseHangfireServer();
}
```

After that I've updated WebApiConfig and registered my Autofac container in Hangfire

```
private static void RegisterDependencies(HttpConfiguration config)
{
     var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
     ...
     var container = builder.Build();
     ...
     config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
     Hangfire.GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseAutofacActivator(container);
}
```

When I try to run Hangfire job like

```
IObject someObject = MyObject();    
var jobId = BackgroundJob.Enqueue<IMyInterface>(x
                    => x.MyMethod(someObject));
```

I get the following error

System.InvalidOperationException
The type MyNamespace.IMyInterface does not contain a method with signature MyMethod(IObject1)` 
at Hangfire.Storage.InvocationData.Deserialize()
What can be the issue?

Comment: I've figured out that resolve doesn't work when interface has generic declaration. Sort of 
public TResult MyMethod<TResult>(IObject<TResult> query)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in hangfire way of work. It serializes parameters and in case of generics can't desirialize it back. The workaround is create a mediator that can be easily serialized/desirialized and run the code you need.

Comment: You should provide an example of the mediator if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following code in Startup.cs file.

```cs
private void ConfigureAutofac(HttpConfiguration config, IAppBuilder app)
{        
   var requestTag = MatchingScopeLifetimeTags.RequestLifetimeScopeTag;
   var jobTag = AutofacJobActivator.LifetimeScopeTag;
   builder.RegisterType<MyClass>().As<IMyInterface>().InstancePerRequest();
}
```